# Data Type Mistmatch in Python trying to update Sqlite3 database with some twitter data

Tags: python, sqlite

I think my problem has to do with the twitter created_at date field but I am not sure.  Here is the table that i think is the problem:

```
 sql_create_tweets_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tweets (
                              id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                              user_id integer NOT NULL,
                              created_at text,
                              short_text text,
                              full_text text
                          ); """
```

I convert my Twitter created_at date in this way:

```
 vcreated_at = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(data['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))
```

This changes the incoming "Tue Nov 13 19:07:58 +0000 2018" to 
"2018-11-13 19:07:58"  which I believe is acceptable to sqLite.  There are only two integer and two text fields included in the update.  So I suspect the date is triggering the error but I am not sure how to check it. When I check the type of created_at and vcreated_at they are both TEXT  as is the table column.

This is the code that tries to add the row but fails:

```
 def updateTables(vcreated_at, vid, vtext, vlongtext, vuser_id, vname, 
 vscreen_name):
# now update the sql file

conn = create_connection(my_file)
if conn is not None:
    cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        cur.execute('''
            INSERT INTO
                tweets 
            VALUES
                (?,?,?,?,?) ''',
                (vcreated_at, vid, vtext, vlongtext, vuser_id))
    except Exception as e: print(e) 

    cur.execute('''
        INSERT INTO 
             users 
        VALUES
            (?,?,?) ''',
            (vuser_id, vname, vscreen_name))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Spent hours working on this but stuck!

Comment: *"11-13-2018 19:07:58" which I believe is acceptable to sqLite.* no it should be 2018-11-13 19:07:58 to be a recognised date.

Comment: That was a type sorry.  the code above does exactly as you say.

Comment: What is the exception you get? I would suggest adding `print(repr((vcreated_at, vid, vtext, vlongtext, vuser_id)))` before the insert to see what the actual values are.

Comment: ('2018-12-20 21:56:45', 1075872658850570240, 'Showdown, with working Americans the victims', '', 1058764970010308611)
datatype mismatch    NOTE the empty field is expected and not required by the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to put a non INTEGER into the **id** column. As the **id** column is an alias of **rowid** (i.e. defined using `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` makes it an alias of the special/normally hidden rowid column) it **must** be an integer value and hence the datatype mismatch error.

- *(INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is a special case that makes the column an alias of the rowid column)* [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) *(autoincrement can only be used for an alias of the rowid)*
- Other than for this exception to the rule, you can put any type of value into any type of column.

To resolve this you could shuffle the parameters/arguments to be `(vid, vuser_id, vcreated_at, vtext, vlongtext)` to suit the expected order of the values.

That is the values are as per the order in which the columns are defined.

Alternately you could use `INSERT INTO tweets (created_at, id, short_text, full_text, user_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)` along with `(vcreated_at, vid, vtext, vlongtext, vuser_id)`.

That is, you specify the columns that the values will be matched to.

Using this option your code would be :-

```
try:
    cur.execute('''
        INSERT INTO
            tweets (created_at, id, short_text, full_text, user_id)
        VALUES
            (?,?,?,?,?) ''',
            (vcreated_at, vid, vtext, vlongtext, vuser_id))
except Exception as e: print(e)
```

- the above assumes that **vid** is an integer and is unique. If **vid** is the same value as exists in the **id** column in another row then you'd get a UNIQUE constraint violation as an alias of rowid is implicitly unique.

Comment: Can you clarify the syntax on your Alternate suggestion - that will work but I am have syntax issues.  Kind of new to this and struggling...

Comment: The SQL should be `INSERT INTO tweets (created_at, id, short_text, full_text, user_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)` i.e. you precede VALUES with the column names (doesn't have to be all columns) enclosed in parenthesises. I've edited the answer to include the code (note not checked or run so may have some typos)

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks